# Tapestry: How to use Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable, tapestry

I am using jquery/datatable. I want to highlight selected row in the datatable. There is sample jQuery code that implements that. Here is the code

```
var oTable;
var giRedraw = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
/* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
$("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});

/* Init the table */
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( );
```

What I did is copy the code into a test.js file and import it. However, it does not work. I even try changing $ to jQuery but it still does not work. I have set configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "false"); in my AppModule. How do I use Jquery with Tapestry?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is on the `html` containing the `id`. `#example`, try to paste here your html code..

Comment: I change the id #example to my id #tableList, but it does not work.

Comment: If you set JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE to false, you can't use '$' for jQuery, but you'll need to use '$j'. You can set your own alias with JQuerySymbolConstants.JQUERY_ALIAS

Comment: I also tried with $j but it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure your JavaScript code was actually called? How did you include it? If you include it using @Import or JavaScriptSupport.importJavaScriptLibrary(), you don't need to wrap your code in a $(document.ready(function(){...}), because Tapestry already does that for you. In addition, you said just that it doesn't work, but haven't mentioned any JavaScript errors.

Comment: I noticed you said you set: configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "false"); which leaves prototype ENABLED.  If you want to actually turn off prototype so that jQuery is using the $ sign, then put: configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "true");  I have recently done a ton of jQuery inside of Tapestry, so if it is still not working, please paste your HTML or any errors you are seeing, and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from http://tapestry5-jquery.com/#block2

> The tapestry5-jquery project has an option permitting you to customize
>   this alias : in your AppModule, contributeApplicationDefaults method,
>   you can add `configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.JQUERY_ALIAS,
>   "yourOwnAlias");`.